# What does the phrase "recommend to" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

This is an excerpt from The Theory of Moral Sentiments by Adam Smith.

Comment: A question I couldn't answer after numerous readings of this paragraph: what is the referent of "it"  in "Those to which **it** is…"?

Comment: "Recommend to", in this sense, means to give the object of "to" (be it a person or organization) a recommendation favorable to the subject.  This is not an "archaic" usage, but it is rather formal.

Answer (score 2):

This use of **recommend** is rare now but at the time of Adam Smith was common but formal:

OED

**recommend**

> **3 b.** *transitive*. **To commit (oneself or another) to a person or thing, or to someone's care, prayers, etc. Cf. recommand v.1 1c. Now rare.**

1713   tr. in R. Steele Guardian No. 17   *He led her to a Relation's House, to whose Care he recommended her for that Night.*

1742   H. Fielding Joseph Andrews I. ii. xi. 245   *Fanny..was..recommended to the Care of a Maid-Servant of the House, who helped her to [...] dress, and clean herself.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

**The same principles that direct the order in which individuals are recommended to our beneficence, direct that likewise in which societies are recommended to it.**

The following is my understanding of the text above:

The same principles that direct the order in which individuals are recommended to use their beneficence (for someone) are also recommended to a society to decide upon its order of beneficence for individuals, which are part of it.

Answer (score -1):

"Order" as used in this text, means certainly

- "*a natural, moral, spiritual, or social system in which things proceed according to definite laws (Middle English)* (Shorter Oxford English Dictionary).

"*Society*" means

- "*The system of customs and organization adopted by a body of (esp. human) individuals for harmonious and interactive coexistence or for muual benefit, defence, etc. (mid 16th century)*".

"Recommend" signifies in this particular context

- "*Procure a favourable reception for; make acceptable or desirable to or* to *a person (early 17th century)*" .

The sentence "*The same principles that direct the order in which individuals are recommended to our beneficence, direct that likewise in which societies are recommended to it.*" has then the following meaning.

- The principles in the system which we use to judge individuals and thus favour some rather than others are the same as the principles in the system ("*that* likewise") we use for the similar purpose of judging societies and favouring some of them over others.

Comment: Using a meaning that is restricted to Middle English for a document that was written in the 18th century is rather dubious. Why do you think this is justified?

Comment: I think that *order* means *ranking* here; otherwise the second sentence (*Those to which ...*) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @PeterShor The period specification is the period of first recorded use; only when two periods appear side by side is the word not in present use (for instance "ME-E16"); the second period is then that of last recorded use.

Comment: @PeterShor Would then individuals be recommend to our beneficence  according to ranking? That is not the case, it would be to restrictive a system.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer! I do have some doubts on the specific words listed above, and among them, "recommend" confuses me most. Now I can thoroughly understand the passage with your help, which is also useful for understanding the whole bookd cuz those words are used so many times in it.